# Integrate Postman test scripts with Jenkins build server

Tags: jenkins, postman

I've downloaded the POSTMAN Chrome app in order to test some Web APIs on my local dev environment.

In addition, I've downloaded the Newman cmd-line utility for Postman.

See https://www.getpostman.com/docs/newman_intro for more info.

So the Postman app is working fine, and the cmd-line utility is working too.

However, once I integrate it with my Jenkins test server, the tests are failing.

The main problem is that it's not able to launch `Newman`.

In a standard cmd prompt, I can successfully run the Newman test script as :

```
  newman -c API-Collection.json -n 3
```

running n number of times.

[image: from cmd prompt]

And in the `Jenkins` build server GUI, I add the build script under the "Execute Shell" option.

[image]

But it doesn't find `Newman`, as this build error shows:

```html
  FailedConsole Output

Started by user anonymous
Building in workspace C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Web Api Test1 (Team Gecko)
[Web Api Test1 (Team Gecko)] $ "C:\Program Files\bin\sh.exe" -xe C:\Windows\TEMP\hudson2522506155962538386.sh
+ newman -c C:\Users\robertjm\Documents\POSTMAN Files\Workbench-API-Collection.json -n 3 -y 1000 --exitCode 1 -o output.json -H output.html
C:\Windows\TEMP\hudson2522506155962538386.sh: newman: command not found
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

If someone can assist me in resolving this path issue, I would appreciate it.

thanks,
Bob

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Final solution was :

1) Add build step "Execute Windows batch command" and add two lines below:

2) change dir to newman\bin:

```
  cd \Users\bob\appdata\roaming\npm\node_modules\newman\bin
```

3) run `node newman` as opposed to simply trying to run `newman`

```
  node newman -c "C:\\Users\\bob\\Documents\\POSTMAN Files\\Workbench-API-Collection.json"
```

The two tricky parts were:

1) running newman like this `newman -c myCollection.json` was not working, as Jenkins could not resolve this node module as it would in a straight Win cmd prompt.

2) Trying to locate the Newman module was difficult, as it's hidden inside `%appdata%` folder (i.e. c:\users\bob\$appdata$ ).

I hope this helps someone in the future.

good luck.

Comment: worked for me as well. but console output is shown in special symbols. Do we need to do something to get it correctly?

Comment: Thank you. For me jenkins did not recognize -c option, i had to use "node newman run <my_path_to_collection_json>"

Answer (score 2):

Run command "which newman" in command prommpt. It will return something like - 
/c/Users/user1/AppData/Roaming/npm/newman

Now use fully qualified path returned by above mentioned command in Jenkins windows batch command box -

c:/Users/user1/AppData/Roaming/npm/newman -c demo.postman_collection.json

Comment: yes thanks, but we already figured that one out. And the `which` cmd not recognized in Windows cmd prompt.

Comment: You can use where command in windows command prompt. I forgot to mention that I use Cmder on windows which supports many unix commands. It's very helpful tool. http://cmder.net

Answer (score 2):

Integrate Postman with Jenkins on Windows Machine

Step #1 : Download Jenkins on your local windows machine .

URL to Download Jenkins :-- https://jenkins.io/download/
After successful download enter :- http://localhost:8080
Step #2 : Enter the name of the project and click on Freestyle project and save .
[image: screen 1]

Step #3 : PostmanScriptTest2 job  gets created and under source code management >build > click on execute windows batch command.
[image: screen 2]

Step #3: Type in command under Execute Windows batch Command

C:\Users\ashish\AppData\Roaming\npm\newman run https://www.getpostman.com/collections/d231549a4assc77abcdbaf9c674

Click on save and apply.
[image: screen3]

Step #4: Go to Jenkins Home Page and click on Manage Jenkins

[image: screen4]
Step #5 : Under manage Jenkins click on configure System .

[image: screen5]

Step #6 : Under Global Properties > check on environmental variables and enter

Name - PATH

Value - C:\Program Files\Nodejs
[image: screen 6]

Step #7 : Under Shell , shell executable type in C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe and click on save and apply .

[image: screen7]