# Executing Newman REST API tests using Jenkins on Linux

Tags: linux, rest, jenkins, newman

I found this answer [Integrate Postman test scripts with Jenkins build server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36632059/integrate-postman-test-scripts-with-jenkins-build-server) (and possibly there are other ones that could answer my question but I just suck at finding them) but I am still running into issues. I am trying to execute the following with newman v3 using jenkins as a way to automate our REST API Testing.

My Execute Shell script looks like this under the Build steps in the jenkins job

```
#!/bin/bash
pwd
cd ${PROJECT_NAME}/${GIT_SUBFOLDER}
pwd
ls
newman run ${COLLECTION_NAME} -e ${ENVIRONMENT_NAME} -r html,cli,json,junit --insecure
```

Ignore the pwds and ls as I originally thought I wasn't in the right directory for my collection and environment exports.

The error I keep getting back in jenkins is:

> /tmp/hudson1153303836033593524.sh: line 6: newman: command not found

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Got your problem, Seems that you are trying to execute your project as shell script in jenkins and jenkins cant get newman
Here is the solution, might solve your problem
**In your script export path where npm modules** get installed
Locate node_modules for your system generally its at
 /usr/local/lib/node_modules
Now add line in your script which will export PATH:

```
#!/bin/bash
export PATH="<Your node_module Path>:$PATH"
pwd
cd ${PROJECT_NAME}/${GIT_SUBFOLDER}
pwd
ls
newman run ${COLLECTION_NAME} -e ${ENVIRONMENT_NAME} -r html,cli,json,junit --insecure
```